# Scrollview and uiview fade in fade out in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, fadein, fadeout

I would like to implement a fade in / fade out transition.
My structure is:

```
UIView
|-UIScrollView // contains array of UILabels
|-UIImageView1
|-UIImageView2
|-UIImageView3
|-UIImageView4
```

Everything works fine if i scroll horizonatally on all the screen's width.
However if I scroll just a bit on right or left, I have a return of scroll in the other direction making my opacities wrong (i can see a bit of next and previous image).

This is my code :

```
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollViewLabels.frame.size.width
    let page:Int = Int(floor((self.scrollViewLabels.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)

    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        // move right

        let opacityPercent:CGFloat = (CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / pageWidth ) / CGFloat(self.pageControl.currentPage + 1)

        if self.pageControl.currentPage  > 0  {
            self.images[self.pageControl.currentPage].alpha =  opacityPercent

            if self.pageControl.currentPage - 1 >= 0 {
                self.images[self.pageControl.currentPage - 1].alpha = 1 - opacityPercent
            }   
        }
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        // move left

        let opacityPercent:CGFloat = (CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / pageWidth ) / CGFloat(self.pageControl.currentPage + 1)

        if self.pageControl.currentPage  < self.images.count - 1 {
            self.images[self.pageControl.currentPage].alpha = 1 - opacityPercent

            if self.pageControl.currentPage + 1 <= self.images.count - 1 {
                self.images[self.pageControl.currentPage + 1].alpha = opacityPercent

            }
        }

    }

    // update the new position acquired
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x

}


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollViewLabels.frame.size.width
    let page:Int = Int(floor((self.scrollViewLabels.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)

    if (self.pageControl.currentPage != page) {

        self.pageControl.currentPage = page
        self.page = page
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(page), 0)


    } 


}
```

Comment: I added a boolean isFetched which must be true to scroll. It goes to true in BeginDragging and goes to false to EndDragging. But it's not very smoothly. No one as a solution ?